# Already defined variable shows an error that its not defined when refferenced

Tags: flutter, function, dart

I have defined a void function called onTap and am trying to refference it in Gesturedetector on onTap property but it displays an error that its not yet defined. I thought it will recognize the function since I have already defined it
Here is my code

```
import 'package:finalproject/components/my_textfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function()? onTap;
  const LoginPage({super.key, required this.onTap});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  void SignIn() {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              //logo
              const Icon(
                Icons.message,
                size: 80,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),

              //welcome back message
              const Text(
                'Welcome Back, You Have Been Missed',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                ),
              ),
              //create space
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              //email textfield
              MyTextField(
                controller: emailController,
                hintText: 'Enter email',
                obsecuretext: false,
              ),
              //create space
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              //password textfield
              MyTextField(
                controller: passwordController,
                hintText: 'Enter password',
                obsecuretext: true,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              //sign in button
              MyButton(
                onTap: () {
                  SignIn();
                },
                text: 'Login',
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              //not a member? register now
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Not A Member?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      // fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 13,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: Widget.onTap,
                    child: const Text(
                      'Create Account',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to remove nullable sign(?) but still its not recognized

Answer (score 0):

[`Widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget-class.html) (uppercase 'W') refers to an abstract class in the Flutter framework. To refer to the current [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) configuration, use [`widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html) (lowercase 'w') instead.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: widget.onTap,
  ...
)
```